# Does Ubuntu 16 include Nautilus?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, dropbox

This started as me trying to find the right dropbox version for my system, but now i'm mostly just generally curious and confused because i can't find a clear answer on this.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix what does that have to do with anything? OP of the dupe question says that's not what they want, so whether it works or not is absolutely irrelevant.

Comment: @muru, I'm not sure... I just know the question from 2011 is broken in 2017.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix so fix it. That's the ethos of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @muru You've fixed my code before you know I'm not that smart. I've got a long to-do list in Win 10 WSL tomorrow FCU day, Aleinware 17 R3 setup, Driver selection for Samsung Pro 960 PCIe Gen 3x4 NVMe and whether or not ACHI or Intel SATA/RST, migrating dual boot from old laptop and just now ME Andromeda character export and import. Then there are the receiving complications at real life work with migration from Windows Navision to Linux SX.e + TWL. I honestly don't know how you do all you do here and keep up with your Google job n Japan.

Answer (score 4):

## The regular Ubuntu 16.04 includes Nautilus

[image: Nautilus 2]

## You can add Dropbox to Nautilus

You are using Dropbox and are asking if Ubuntu 16.04 includes Nautilus, which it does. You might be interested to learn that you can [add Dropbox to Nautilus](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332623)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Ubuntu 16.04 with the default desktop environment (Unity) does. The default file manager application for Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) called *Files* (*GNOME Files* to be precise) is [formerly and internally known as Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files).

You can make sure Ubuntu 16.04 includes Nautilus (and it is actually the Files application) in multiple ways.

1. Run

   ```
   apt-cache policy nautilus
   ```

   In the output there should be a version number next to `Installed:` instead of `Installed: (none)`.
2. Run `nautilus` in Terminal, Files will be launched.
3. Open Files. Open Terminal and run `xprop`. The mouse pointer should change to a crosshair. Place the crosshair over Files window and click. It should list many info about the window, which includes

   ```
    WM_CLASS(STRING) = "nautilus", "Nautilus"
   ```

Comment: It's worth noting that all versions of the GNOME desktop environment that include GNOME Files have "nautilus", which is the internally used and executable name for the GNOME Files program.